# Use winformchart in a UserControl in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to get a chart displayed in a UserControl. When doing it in Window it works fine.

The xaml code:

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host" Height="300" Width="300">
  <winformchart:Chart x:Name="MyWinformChart">
    <winformchart:Chart.Series>
      <winformchart:Series Name="series" ChartType="Line"/>
    </winformchart:Chart.Series>
    <winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
      <winformchart:ChartArea/>
    </winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
  </winformchart:Chart>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace DragonLink.View {
    public partial class TXSpectrumAnalyzer : UserControl {
        Dictionary<int, double> value;
        public TXSpectrumAnalyzer() {
            InitializeComponent();

            value = new Dictionary<int, double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                value.Add(i, 10 * i);

             Chart chart = this.FindName("MyWinformChart") as Chart;
             chart.ChartAreas.Add("Default");
             chart.DataSource = value;
             chart.Series["series"].XValueMember = "Key";
             chart.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "Value";
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code in a Window works just fine.

Why won't this work in a UserControl? What would be some other way to display a winForm chart?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. For some reason the chart is not displayed when the window has the property AllowsTransparency set to True. Changing this to False and it worked.